# Reshaping tensors in tensorflow.js to an unusual shape [-1, 9, 9, 512]

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to reshape the given image input to a tensor input with shape [-1, 9, 9, 512], to feed into a VGG19-based architecture. This shape comes from the convolutional layers which are roughly corresponding to below (though using 300x300 images instead of 244x244):

[Model Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy8lC.png)

I'm not sure how to rescale the image appropriately to approximate this structure. So far, my javascript looks like this:

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>

</script>
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Architectural Style Classifier 1.0</p>

<img id="imgcanvas" width="300" height="300" src='testimage1.jpg'></img>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
async function run(){

  const image = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgcanvas);
  const resizedimage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(image, [9,9]);
  const batchedImage = tf.expandDims(resizedimage, axis=0);
  const paddedImage = tf.pad(batchedImage, [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0][4,509]]);
  const MODEL_URL = 'web_model/model.json';
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(MODEL_URL);
  const result = model.predict(paddedImage);
  result.print();
}
run();
</script>
</html>
```

I don't think I'm using the padding (or bilinear rescaling) appropriately, but without it my tensor is shaped [1,9,9,3] and I don't know how to get from there to [-1,9,9,512]...should I rescale to 300x300 instead of 9x9 and use a different approach to create the 512 channels? How do I make the first dimension -1 rather than 1? Or is that important?

I'm very new to Tensorflow and still don't 100% understand the structure of tensors - I would appreciate any clarity. I created the model roughly by following this blog post:

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-cnn-multi-image-classifier-31c463324fa

Comment: Any update on how you achieved it?